# Sound Library Organizer for Linux?

Tags: software, sfx, linux, file-organization

I'm looking for a sound library organizer working on Linux and capable of handling several thousands of SFX files.

The software I found until now are mostly players with some built-in management capabilities. But I'm looking for something more tailored toward the editing process like AudioFinder or Resonic Pro, having at least deep metadata extraction, playback loops, and pitch shifting so I don't have to jump into Ardour to "test" each file in my selection.

Both because I could tweak the software in case of need, and also for financial reasons, I would prefer an opensource solution. But at this point, I'm ready to consider any option as long as the work is done.

Answer (score -1):

take a look at beets.io which is a metadata catalog for linux.

Comment: Hello. Could you give some details on how the linked software does answer to the OP's question ? At first sight, it seems that it doesn't offer editing functionalities that were mentioned by the OP.

Comment: I already look at beets:

https://discourse.beets.io/t/how-to-use-beets-to-manage-sfx-library/469

It has some potential, but it definitely lacks features for my use case--especially since it **does not handle the WAV file format** !